# Using In-band commissioning with SAMR21s ftd cli returns Join failed [InvalidArgs]

Tags: openthread

Im trying the guide at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/openthread-hardware/#8, with two SAMR21s running the SAMR21 ftd cli examples. Everything seems to work until I need to do joiner start J01NME, which returns with Join failed [InvalidArgs].

Fresh upload of SAMR21 ftd cli examples with parameters COMMISSIONER=1 JOINER=1 DHCP6_CLIENT=1 DHCP6_SERVER=1 on both SAMR21s.

With the two SAMR21s I typed the following commands into the clis:

### SAMR21 1:

> dataset init new

> dataset commit active

> ifconfig up

> thread start

> state

leader

> commissioner start

Commissioner: petitioning

done

> commissioner joiner add 0004251918018576 J01NME

done

### SAMR21 2:

> eui64

0004251918018576

> ifconfig up

>scan

| J | Network Name     | Extended PAN     | PAN  | MAC Address      | Ch | dBm | LQI |

| 1 | OpenThread-f171  | 1b6239e953fd2be4 | f171 | 76144ebb984c039a |  0 |  -7 |   0 |

> joiner start J01NME

done

> Join failed [InvalidArgs]

### Observations

I have noticed when the commissioner times out the follow is displayed which doesnt seem right, as the eui64 being removed doesnt match what i added:

> commissioner joiner add 0004251918018576 J01NME

Done

> Commissioner: Joiner remove b34a468958787c5e

Any help would be appreciated thanks.